# How can I return back to my previous location after I have already committed a change

Tags: git

I have just used Git programming. The problem case is as follows:

" I have just committed my changes on a master branch, and generated a patch on that. 
Actually I just want to save the patch and return back to the position before I did this commit? How can I do that?"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run `git log`, you find the sha1 of the commit you want to go to, and you run

```
git checkout <sha1>
```

If you want to start commiting from this point you create a new branch at this point with

```
git checkout -b <branchname>
```

Or you can just move `master` to this sha1 with

```
git br -f master <sha1>; git checkout master
```

Comment: yeah I think `git checkout <sha1>` is not recommended because you get in DETACHED_HEAD mode and it is not really easy to get out of it (especially for someone not comfortable with Git)

Comment: Can I do this : "git reset --hard HEAD@{1}" since I just want to roll back to the previous commit on the same branch.

Comment: `HEAD@{1}` is not exactly the previous commit, its the last position of the HEAD, so in your case it will work if commiting was exactly the last operation you did. The correct command is `git reset --hard HEAD^` as it will move your pointer one commit backward.

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve your commit SHA, i.e. you run `git show` and see the one you want, then you branch from it:

`git checkout -b yournewbranch commitSHA`